# IEnumerable method return squared int

Tags: c#, .net, integer

I am new to C# and found a method I can't quite finish making work. The method is supposed to take an array and return it with all integers squared.

What I don't understand is the `<long>` return type or why it would be needed and the fact that if an item that is more than int's MaxValue is passed, then the method doesn't change it in any way when it's supposed to return it as 0.

What I want is if an array like `new long[] {4294967296, 4295098369, 4611686014132420609}` is passed to it, it would return `{0, 0, 0}`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EnumerableTask
{
    public class EnumerableManipulation
    {
        public IEnumerable<long> GetSquareSequence(IEnumerable<int> data)
        {
        /// <summary>Transforms integer sequence to its square sequence
        /// <param name="data">Source int sequence.</param>
        ///   Returns sequence of squared items.
            foreach (int item in data)
            {
                if (item == null)
                {
                    yield return 0;
                }                
                else if (item > int.MaxValue)
                {
                    yield return 0;
                }
                yield return item * item;
///For some reason just returns an item's value if it's more than int.MaxValue. Why?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int cannot have value greater then int.MaxValue, it will have some negative vaule because of overflow

Comment: The `long` return type is easy to explain: `int.MaxValue` squared doesn't fit in an `int`, but it does fit in a `long`. To actually perform the calculation so it yields a `long`, however, you have to convert the operand first: `yield return (long) item * item`. Note that the test for `null` is entirely useless and the compiler should have told you so: an `int` is never `null`. Nor is an `int` ever greater than `int.MaxValue`, by definition, so the whole thing can be simplified to just the `yield`.

Comment: Change input type to `IEnumerable<long>`. Otherwise, you will have overflow as now.

Comment: The highest int value that you can square, which fits in an `Int32` is 46,340. Everything above that will overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (item == null)
```

primitive types like `int` cannot be null, so this is redundant.

```
 else if (item > int.MaxValue)
```

An int cannot be larger than `int.MaxValue`. Perhaps you intended to tale a list of `long`? i.e. `GetSquareSequence(IEnumerable<long> data)` ? Otherwise you should not need that check.

When using any arithmetic operation on values you may run the risk of overflow, i.e. that the result is larger than the number of bits used to represent the value. This is especially an issue when multiplying large numbers. But since a long is twice as many bits, you should not need any overflow checking. So your whole code should be possible to replace with

```
foreach (long item in data)
{
    yield return item * item;
}
```

or just

```
var squared list = myList.Select(i => (long)i * i);
```

If you want to use the same return type as input type with overflow checking, you might want to use [checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) expressions to find such cases and handle them somehow.

Comment: @fildor good point. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have *integer overflow* on `item * item`, to prevent it `cast` `item` *before* multiplication:

```
// static : we don't want "this" here, so we can declare it as static 
public static IEnumerable<long> GetSquareSequence(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    // the method is public we should validate user input
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data)); // or yield break;

    // long item  - we should multiply longs, not ints:
    // item is long; int.MaxValue * int.MaxValue < long.MaxValue   
    foreach (long item in data)
        yield return item * item; 
}
```

Please note, that *both* of your conditions are of no use: `if (item == null) {...}` will never be true (since `int` is `struct` and thus can't be `null`); `if (item > int.MaxValue)` will never be true since `int` value can't be beyond *its own maximum value*

Answer (score 0):

The `item` can not be larger than `int.MaxValue` because data type of `item` is `int` and the maximum value of `int` is exactly `int.MaxValue`.

If you want pass larger value than `int` you must use larger data type. Don't know your case in detail, but using `IEnumerable<long>` instead of `IEnumerable<int>` may be to solution for you.